# Probability in experiments

Tags: probability

In certain experiments, the error made in determining the density of a
silicon compound is a random variable having the probability density function

$$ f_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
25 & -0.02 \lt x \lt 0.02 \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases} $$
Find the probabilities that such an error will be

(a) between $-0.03$ and $0.04$

(b) between $-0.005$ and $0.005$.

I don`t know how to begin.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. This is not a "solve this for me" site.

Comment: Do you know what a probability density function is, and how it relates to a cumulative distribution function? if not, look this up, if you do, work it out using this

Answer (score 2):

The $support$ of the random variable $X$ is $x\in(-0.02,0.02)$ so we know for sure that $x\in(-0.03,0.04)$ as well.

For a probability density function $f_X(x)$ we have

$P[a\leq X\leq b]=\int _{a}^{b}f_{X}(x)\,dx$

That should be enough for you to solve part $(b)$

Comment: So easy! Thanks!